# Fetching plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage@1.0.6" via npm Failed to fetch plugin cordova-sqlite-storage

Tags: sqlite, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Hi I am now building my **iOS** application from cli 5.40 to **cli-6.3.0** for production use and Im using **brodysoft sqlite plugin** to store all the data in my applications then after uploading the application to **build.phonegap.com**, I got this error below:

```
Error - Plugin (or a specific plugin version) not found in external repo: cordova-sqlite-storage@1.0.6": Fetching plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage@1.0.6" via npm Failed to fetch plugin cordova-sqlite-storage
```

Here's my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
-->
<widget  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets' id='com.testApp' xmlns:gap= "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" version= "11.22.16">
  <name>
  App
  </name>
  <description>

  </description>
  <author email='email' href='http://test.com'>
    Energy Systems
  </author>

    <!-- SET Platform to build by Phonegap. -->
  <gap:platform name="ios" />

<!-- Grant certain URLs the ability to launch external applications. This
        behaviour is set to match that of Cordova versions before 3.6.0, and
        should be reviewed before launching an application in production. It
        may be changed in the future. -->
<allow-intent href='http://*/*'/>
<allow-intent href='https://*/*'/>
<allow-intent href='tel:*'/>
<allow-intent href='sms:*'/>
<allow-intent href='mailto:*'/>
<allow-intent href='geo:*'/>
<allow-intent href='itms:*'/>
<allow-intent href='itms-apps:*'/>
<!-- SET Phonegap version to be used in the application. -->

  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />

      <!-- SET DEVICE Set Common SET UP -->
  <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />

  <!-- Define app icons for IOS platform. -->

  <icon src="icon.png" />
  <!-- default 512 pixels -->

  <icon src="resources/icons/icon76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
  <!-- iPad non retina iOS7 -->
  <icon src="resources/icons/icon120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
  <!-- iPhone & iPod Touch retina iOS7 -->
  <icon src="resources/icons/icon152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
  <!-- iPad retina iOS7 -->

  <!--SET UP SPLASH SCREENS -->

  <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
  <!-- default 320x480 pixels -->

  <gap:splash src="resources/splash/splashs320x480.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
  <!-- iPhone & iPod Touch non retina -->
  <gap:splash src="resources/splash/splashs640x960.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
  <!-- iPhone & iPod Touch retina 4- -->
  <gap:splash src="resources/splash/splashs640x1136.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
  <!-- iPhone & iPod Touch retina 5+ -->
  <gap:splash src="resources/splash/splashs1024x768.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
  <!-- iPad non retina -->
  <gap:splash src="resources/splash/splashs768x1024.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
  <!-- iPad non retina -->
  <gap:splash src="resources/splash/splashs2048x1496.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" />
  <!-- iPad retina -->
  <gap:splash src="resources/splash/splashs1536x2008.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" />
  <!-- iPad retina -->

  <!-- If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
    following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
    permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires. -->
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

  <!--<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />-->

  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />

  <!-- to enable individual native permissions use the following  -->

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~2.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="~1.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" spec="~1.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" spec="~1.0.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="1.0.6" source="npm"/>

  <access origin='*'/>

  <content src='index.html'/>
</widget>
```

May I know how to reference brodysoft SQLite storage in config.xml.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the plugin and then add again and build

Comment: No luck, error still occurs.

Comment: Remove the platform and again add platform add build

Comment: Check whether you are logged in using Administrator account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1).** You can try writing this in your config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage"/>
```

just remove the version specified,it will download the latest stable version from the npm repository.

**Or**

You can also add from git repository.

```
// install plugin from a git repository (name is optional)
<plugin spec="https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free.git#0.8.2" source="git" />
```

Comment: Hi AJ I got this error : Error - Plugin error (you probably need to remove plugin files from your app): Fetching plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage" via npm Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" at "1.5.0" for ios Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert... Failed to install 'cordova-sqlite-storage':

Comment: <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1"/> 
Try this version, latest version is having issue i guess with the pgb.

Comment: I added this code plugin name="cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free" source="npm" spec="0.8.0" as well as plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" in my config.xml file but still no luck to make it working. The application was successfully build in Build.Phonegap.com but the app cant load data retrieve from server to sqlite. My device is Ipad iOS 10.

Comment: Have you try adding the plugin via git repository in PGB, try the second way.

Comment: Im now trying git, i ll post the answer after i got the solution. Can you please try it also on your end. Thanks!

Comment: I have added that plugin already, it is added successfully, updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks AJ,  i accepted your answer but this <plugin spec="https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free.git#0d6521e" /> works for me.